# Could not find the correct Provider<AppState> above this MapSample Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have been following a tutorial on cloning a flutter uber app and keep getting an error with  which says: 
**  Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MapSample Widget** , i am trying to add geolocation to my app, i have added both mine and the tutorial source code below, i am a bit new to flutter so forgive any obvious questions, please and thank you

**this is my source code:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:awesome/app_state.dart';




void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(


      title: 'Flutter Google Maps Demo',

      home: MapSample(),
      )

    );
  }
}







class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State < MapSample > createState() => MapSampleState();
}




class MapSampleState extends State < MapSample > {


Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();


  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-13.9875107, 33.768144),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );



  static final CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
    bearing: 192.8334901395799,
    target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
    tilt: 59.440717697143555,
    zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GoogleMapController mapController;
        final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);


     return new Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
              iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),

      ),
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,

      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Trip History'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Payment'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Settings'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),


      body: 

      Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(


        mapToolbarEnabled: false,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: appState.initialPosition, zoom: 10.0),

        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);


          mapController = controller;
          mapController.setMapStyle('[ { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#d6e2e6" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#cfd4d5" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#7492a8" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "lightness": 25 } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape.man_made", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#dde2e3" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape.man_made", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#cfd4d5" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape.natural", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#dde2e3" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape.natural", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#7492a8" } ] }, { "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#dde2e3" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -100 } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#588ca4" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#a9de83" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#bae6a1" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.sports_complex", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#c6e8b3" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.sports_complex", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#bae6a1" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -45 }, { "lightness": 10 }, { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#41626b" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#c1d1d6" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#a6b5bb" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9fb6bd" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -70 } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.line", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#b4cbd4" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.line", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#588ca4" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#008cb5" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station.airport", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": -5 } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#a6cbe3" } ] } ]');

          //_controller.setMapStyle('');

        },
      ),

      Positioned(
                  top: 105.0,
                  right: 30.0,
                  left: 40.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 55,
                    width: 70.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            spreadRadius: 3)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,

                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                      onSubmitted: (value) {

                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 0,bottom: 6),
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.local_taxi,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Hello, Where to?",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
  ],
),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        child: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ), 







    );
  }

  Future < void > _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
}
```

**This is the error visual studio code is giving me**

````
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter ( 5872): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building MapSample(dirty, state:
    I/flutter ( 5872): MapSampleState#6cfd9):
    I/flutter ( 5872): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppState> above this MapSample Widget
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872): This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
    I/flutter ( 5872): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
    I/flutter ( 5872):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   Make sure that MapSample is under your MultiProvider/Provider<AppState>.
    I/flutter ( 5872):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   For example, instead of:
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   ```
    I/flutter ( 5872):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    I/flutter ( 5872):     return Provider<Example>(
    I/flutter ( 5872):       create: (_) => Example(),
    I/flutter ( 5872):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
    I/flutter ( 5872):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
    I/flutter ( 5872):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    I/flutter ( 5872):     ),
    I/flutter ( 5872):   }
    I/flutter ( 5872):   ```
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   consider using `builder` like so:
    I/flutter ( 5872):
    I/flutter ( 5872):   ```
    I/flutter ( 5872):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    I/flutter ( 5872):     return Provider<Example>(
    I/flutter ( 5872):       create: (_) => Example(),
    I/flutter ( 5872):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
    I/flutter ( 5872):       builer: (context) {
    I/flutter ( 5872):         // No longer throws
    I/flutter ( 5872):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    I/flutter ( 5872):       }
    I/flutter ( 5872):     ),
    I/flutter ( 5872):   }
    I/flutter ( 5872):   ```
    ( 5872):
I/flutter ( 5872): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
I/flutter ( 5872): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
I/flutter ( 5872):
I/flutter ( 5872): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 5872):   MapSample 
package:awesome/main.dart:29
I/flutter ( 5872):
I/flutter ( 5872): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5872): #0      Provider._inheritedElementOf 
package:provider/src/provider.dart:258
I/flutter ( 5872): #1      Provider.of 
package:provider/src/provider.dart:210
I/flutter ( 5872): #2      MapSampleState.build 
package:awesome/main.dart:72
I/flutter ( 5872): #3      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
I/flutter ( 5872): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
I/flutter ( 5872): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4675
I/flutter ( 5872): #6      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4218
I/flutter ( 5872): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4481
I/flutter ( 5872): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4666
I/flutter ( 5872): #9      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4476
I/flutter ( 5872): ...     Normal element mounting (115 frames)
I/flutter ( 5872): #124    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3446
I/flutter ( 5872): #125    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5947
I/flutter ( 5872): ...     Normal element mounting (256 frames)
I/flutter ( 5872): #381    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3446
I/flutter ( 5872): #382    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3214
I/flutter ( 5872): #383    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1148
I/flutter ( 5872): #384    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1119
I/flutter ( 5872): #385    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1061
I/flutter ( 5872): #386    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2607
I/flutter ( 5872): #387    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1060
I/flutter ( 5872): #388    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:941
I/flutter ( 5872): #389    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:922
I/flutter ( 5872): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 5872):
````

**And this is the original tutorial source code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:uber_clone/states/app_state.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Map());
  }
}

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: appState.initialPosition == null
          ? Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
              SpinKitRotatingCircle(
              color: Colors.black,
                size: 50.0,
              )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: appState.locationServiceActive == false,
                    child: Text("Please enable location services!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),),
                  )
                ],
              )
            )
          : Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: appState.initialPosition, zoom: 10.0),
                  onMapCreated: appState.onCreated,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  compassEnabled: true,
                  markers: appState.markers,
                  onCameraMove: appState.onCameraMove,
                  polylines: appState.polyLines,
                ),

                Positioned(
                  top: 50.0,
                  right: 15.0,
                  left: 15.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            spreadRadius: 3)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      controller: appState.locationController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5),
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.location_on,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "pick up",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Positioned(
                  top: 105.0,
                  right: 15.0,
                  left: 15.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            spreadRadius: 3)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      controller: appState.destinationController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        appState.sendRequest(value);
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5),
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.local_taxi,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "destination?",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

//        Positioned(
//          top: 40,
//          right: 10,
//          child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _onAddMarkerPressed,
//          tooltip: "aadd marker",
//          backgroundColor: black,
//          child: Icon(Icons.add_location, color: white,),
//          ),
//        )
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't create `AppState` provider and you are trying to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call provider before use. You can use a multi-provider like this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppState>(
            create: (_) => AppState()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
```